Why is x[] not a variable?
Variables[x[0]] returns {x[0]} and Variables[x[k]] returns {x[k]}, but Variables[x[]] returns {}.
I want equations involving x[], and I want them to treat x[] as a variable, is there a way?

You can use Cases[{2 x[]^3 + 1, x[1]^2 + x[3]^3}, _x, All] instead.

Perhaps you should define your own variables function as Union[Variables[#], myvariables[#]]& which picks the missing parts.

@mikado yes, I am doing things like Prepend[Select[Variables[expr],Head[#]===x&],x[]] but when you have to repeat it again and again you start wondering about a sensible shortcut...

Besides, strictly speaking this is unsafe, one has to actually check wheter x[] is present somewhere in expr

I would suggest a slight alteration to your representation. Instead of
x @@ # & /@ Subsets[Range[3]]
(* {x[], x[1], x[2], x[3], x[1, 2], x[1, 3], x[2, 3], x[1, 2, 3]} *)

do
x /@ Subsets[Range[3]]
(* {x[{}], x[{1}], x[{2}], x[{3}], x[{1, 2}], x[{1, 3}], x[{2, 3}], x[{1, 2, 3}]} *)

And instead of
Solve[eqs, Select[vars, Length[Level[#, 1]] < 2 &]]

do
Solve[eqs, Select[eqs, LessThan[2]@*Apply[Length]]]

Also, it's not relevant to your question but there is a function MapApply that combines Map and Apply. So, instead of
f @@ # & /@ list

you can do
f @@@ list


Very good solution, thank you! Also thank you for informing me about MapApply, good to know!

Perhaps the following:
Clear[x]
x[] := x[""]


Variables /@ {2 x[]^3 + x[1]^2, x[1]^2 + x[3]^3}


{{x[1], x[""]}, {x[1], x[3]}}


Hmm, it is an option, but in my calculations it is very convenient to use things like x @@ # & /@ Subsets[Range[3]] or Solve[eqs,Select[vars,Length[Level[#,1]]<2&]
